# Automatically updating google spreadsheet with data from bigquery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

Followed the instructions [here](https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/big-query-and-google-spreadsheet-intergration/) and integrated a google spreadsheet with bigQuery. My query pulls data from the past hour, so it is important to keep the spreadsheet updated.

Is there a way for the sheet to automatically run the script and update the data on refreshing the page? Right now, I need to perform a few clicks to do it.

Comment: Refreshing the page triggers the "onOpen()" simple trigger, or an installed "on open" trigger.  So, you need an "On Open" trigger, either the simple or installed.  [Apps Script Documentation - Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Thx. I tried that, but that gives an authentication error if I refresh the page. But if I follow the manual steps, the data get refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition to @Sandy Good's answer.

You need to use [`onOpen(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), it runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document or form that has permission to edit.

```
function onOpen() {
// Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
.createMenu('Custom Menu')
.addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
.addToUi();
}
```

You received authorization error since script needs authorization. Apps Script requires user authorization to access data.

If a script uses services that can access private data, you'll see one of the authorization dialog.

You may revoke scripts access by following these steps:

- Visit the permissions page for your Google account. (To navigate to this page in the future, visit Google.com, then click your account picture in the top-right corner of the screen. Next, click Account, then Security, then View all in the account permissions section.)
- Click the name of the script whose authorization you want to revoke, then click Revoke access on the right.

For more information regarding authorization, please follow the Official Google Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Since BigQuery has already been integrated to Google Spreadsheet,
here's what you have to do with your Script:

**1.** Send HTTP request using [**`Datasets: update`**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/update#top_of_page) with added path parameters `datasetId` and `projectId`.

**Sample HTTP request:**

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/datasets/datasetId
```

However, please note of the following when using `Datasets: update`:

- It requires authorization as stated in [Authenticating requests to the Google BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authentication#app-default-cred)
- The specified access list completely overwrites the existing access list. If you specify an empty access list, you will revoke access to everyone except yourself
- This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes:

**Scope**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

**2.** To update your data automatically, you can set up a [Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#getting_started) function from inside your Script which executes based on  your preferences with these reserved function names:

- `onOpen(e)` runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, or form that he or she has permission to edit.
- `onEdit(e)` runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.
- `onInstall(e)` runs when a user installs an add-on.
- `doGet(e)` runs when a user visits a web app or a program sends an HTTP `GET` request to a web app.
- `doPost(e)` runs when a program sends an HTTP `POST` request to a web app.

Again, you should also note that because simple triggers fire automatically, they are subject to several restrictions which you can go through in the documentation.